# How to write data to end of line of existing file (STM32CubeMX FATFS SDIO issue)?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, fat, sdio

I have successfully coded write data into a CSV file is an SD card using STM32 CubeMS FATFS SDIO interface 1-bit mode.

But I can't find the file append function in HAL FATFS driver to write data to existing file. Is there another way to do this using STM32CubeMX and HAL drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you would on other platforms.

**Open the file for append**

The [`f_open()`](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/open.html) function has a `FA_OPEN_APPEND` flag, which makes subsequent `f_write()` functions to append data at the end of the file.

**Move the file pointer to the end of the file**

If the file can't be opened in append mode (e.g. when existing data must be accessed first), then you can set the file pointer to the length of the file.

```
f_lseek(fp, f_size(fp));
```

Comment: I tried putting FA_OPEN_APPEND but it is not available in stm32 hal fatfs lib

Comment: Update to the latest version. It has appeared in FatFS version `R0.12a (July 10, 2016)`